# high RAM usage on ubuntu desktop

Tags: ram, swap, programming, jupyter, ram-usage

I'm using an Ubuntu desktop 20.04 LTS.
I'm not running any concurrent applications at the time.
and I'm using R and python and a jupyter notebook in my computer.

today while running jupyter notebook I got an unresponsive page issue and I checked the monitor app
and unbelievably saw 90% of my RAM and even 70% of swap area is busy.
I dont know how to fix this .
by the way my pc has 6 Gib of RAM and 12 Gib of swap area.

Comment: hi .I mentioned what I meant to say.

Comment: Did you look at `top` to see what the big memory-using processes are?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo swapon -s` and `top`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just decreate the desired RAM usage of your Jupyter Notebook:

`jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.max_buffer_size=3`

Which should set it to 3gb max.
I have found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58146531).